# Search through identical links and return first match. - Python BS4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, python-re

I'm trying collect an input and I want the first link match to be printed. I can't seem to figure it out so I'm here. Any ideas would be great thanks

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
import requests


result = requests.get("https://naruto-arena.net/characters-and-skills")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all("a", { "class" : "subjlink"})


name = input("Enter name: ")

for link in links:
href = (link.attrs['href'])
if name.lower() in href[30:].replace("-", "").lower():
    print(href)
```

Result:

Enter name: naruto

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Uzumaki-Naruto

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Kyuubi-Naruto

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Uzumaki-Naruto-(S)

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Sennin-Naruto-(S)

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Four-Tail-Kyuubi-Naruto-(S)

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Kyuubi-Naruto-(S)

Desired result:

https://naruto-arena.net/char/Uzumaki-Naruto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your links match, with "naruto" near the end of all of them. If you want just one to be printed, you'll need a break statement. You also seem to have mis-indented your code, as the lines immediately after your `for` loop are not indented. Here's something that should work:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
for link in links:
    href = (link.attrs['href'])
    if name.lower() in href[30:].replace("-", "").lower():
        print(href)
        break
```

Hope that helps, Happy Coding!